# WildCard Domains without subdomain mapping

Tags: wordpress, apache, .htaccess, dns, multisite

So I am working on WordPress Multisite installation, went to setup the subdomain mapping for the wildcard domains. *.example.com and found the hosting provider this person is using doesn't support wildcard domains. Now I am wondering if their is some sort of work around maybe using .htaccess I started trying somethings but could use some help this is where I am at:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.+)\.example\.com$   [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.example\.com$  [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://example.com/index.php  [L,R]
```

Kind of hitting a wall, any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your hosting provider doesn't support wildcard domains you have two options.

1. switch hoster
2. manually add the subdomains when you create a sub-site.

Comment: No options of being creative with some .htaccess rewrites? I tried a few things but I just can't believe there is no other options..Guess I need to get this guy to switch hosts.

Comment: Domains and mapping of those are done on vhost level. Which is higher then `.htaccess` It's not abnormal to have this locked down by a hosting party. Especially on shared hosts.